# transaction failed - out of gas (when receiving REAL tokens)

Tags: gas, erc-20, myetherwallet

I have participated in an ICO and should receive the REAL Tokens in my MyEtherWallet. The transaction failed due to out of gas. After this error, I added the necessary ETH in my MyEtherWallet to cover the TX fee for the transaction to be completed.

How can the transaction be reloaded and the contract to be executed and to receive my REAL Tokens ? Please help me... 
TX etherscan `0x70fc74551a132a301e5b4a6c1c6dbbfe23d4a6479501b60c6468cd2f6ba0cf3b`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You set a gas limit of `60000` which is very low for a token transaction. On the **Send Ether and Tokens** there is an input for **Gas limit** set it to something high like `200,000` so the transaction goes through. You can set the gas price low (in top bar of MEW) if you are not in hurry.

Recall that:

Cost of Transaction = gasLimit * gasPrice.

So even with a high limit, you don't have to spend a lot if you are willing set the gasPrice low and wait a few blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you increase your gas limit? If not, I would suggest finding the gas requirements on the ICO website, or you could just simply set your gas limit to around 230,000 gas, which in most cases will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling Transfer? Usually (99% of the time) transfer is meant to send tokens from person A to person B. To buy tokens, you will want to use another function. I would consult their website/their team on the correct function to use to purchase tokens with their smart contract.